# How to fix this jQuery Scope mistake?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Something I'm not able to figure out in this code, I think it's a scoping issue.

I have the following javascript snippet

```
<javascript language="javascript>
    $(function() {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false
        });

        function getMessage(direction, msgId) {
            return "This is an " + direction + " message with ID: " + msgId;
        }

        function showMessage(direction, msgId) {
            $("#dialog").text(getMessage(direction, msgId));
            $("#dialog").dialog('open');
        }
    });
</script>
```

That I want to call it like the following

```
<div id="dialog" title="Message Info"></div>
<input type="button" id="btnCommand1" value="Command 1" onclick="javascript: showMessage('Outgoing', 1000487874')" />
<input type="button" id="btnCommand2" value="Command 2" onclick="javascript: showMessage('Incoming', 2000237851')" />
```

I understand that I can bind the click event through jQuery also but
because I create those buttons dynamically I need to call it like mentioned above.
The problem I get an error that showMessage() is not defined. I found that, in general, methods defined within jQuery scope $(function(){}) are not accessible from outside this scope! how to solve this?

Comment: you can bind the click event even if you create the buttons dynamically. use jquery.live or delegates function and you're good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needn't put everything inside the the `$()` ready handler. The is really just for stuff essential for knowing the page is ready.

Late-binding is good, however, so let's get it working. How would we solve this?

Bind in the jQuery `$()` function using `live()`:

```
$(function(){
    ....
    function showMessage(direction, msgId) {
        $("#dialog").text(getMessage(direction, msgId));
        $("#dialog").dialog('open');
    }

    $("#button1").live("click", function(){
        showMessage('Outgoing', 1000487874);
    });
});
```

If the parameters are dynamic, you can include them as data attributes:

```
<input type="button" id="btnCommand1" value="Command 1" data-param1="Outgoing" data-param2="1000487874" />
```

And access them like so:

```
    $("#button1").live("click", function(){
        showMessage($(this).attr("data-param1"), $(this).attr("data-param2"));
    });
```

I've also noticed a small error in your HTML onlick attribute, with one extra quote at the end of the number:

```
onclick="javascript: showMessage('Outgoing', 1000487874')"
//should be:
onclick="javascript: showMessage('Outgoing', 1000487874)"
//or:
onclick="javascript: showMessage('Outgoing', '1000487874')"
```

Answer (score 2):

> javascript:

That is a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) and doesn't mean "This is JavaScript code". You [specify that onclick attributes contain JavaScript](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.2.1) with meta data.

> because I create those buttons dynamically I need to call it like mentioned above.

That is a false premise.

> I found that in general methods defined within jQuery scope $(function(){}) are not accessible from outside this scope! how to solve this?

**Move the functions outside that anonymous function**

Comment: Creating buttons dynamically means I create them through ASP.NET code. The javascript snippet above is defined once (say in header) & I need to use it as many as required by ASP.NET generated buttons. So It's not a false premise. Event buttons names are not known till it's generated by ASP.NET.

Comment: @Waheed, you don't need to know the names of the buttons. As long as you have a class or any other attribute, you can bind the method to it. Doesn't matter whether it's created later

Comment: @JohnP This is a good one, thanks. I'll use one class for all of them & try using .live() mentioned by James W.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're calling from the global scope, the JS method needs to be in th same scope as well.

You have two options.

1. You can use jquery binding using `.live` so it doesn't matter whether it's dynamically created or not.
2. You can move the methods out of the `$(function(){})` and into the global scope.

Comment: Actual methods contains Ajax calls that requires to stay within $(function(){}) scope. In the same time button names are unknown till they are generated later by ASP.NET So? :)

Comment: Why do AJAX calls need to stay withing `$(function){}`. That call is just a synonym for `document.ready` which itself is used to make sure you don't fire your JS code too early. Since we're talking about method declarations, that point becomes moot. Also, you don't need to know the names of the buttons. Just give them a class and let the JS do the work

Comment: Thanks John, It seems that I got something wrong about $(function){}. I'll check more resources & let everyone what solved this issue.